# How to connect to AWS EC2 instance using filezillla?

Tags: amazon-ec2, filezilla

I have AWS EC2 instance. I am using filezilla 3.8.0 but I cannot connect instance, filezilla doesnt accept account type normal and asking password. When I type user name ubunbu and password blank I received following message:

Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

I inserted pem key and converted ppk key also. My staff can connect but I cant. What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More specifically here's a screenshot of the dialog where you are supposed to add your ssh private key.

[image: ssh key]

Comment: Something wrong with your key. Have you tried connecting using regular ssh ?

Comment: ftp is easy, regular ssh metod is not..I will get crazy..I dont have any problem with the key.

Comment: I did it..I found private key and I used it. For connection instance via filezilla or SSH  u need private key, not a key pair..Thanks to all

Answer (score 13):

It happens in AWS EC2. As EC2 provide Connection through an SFTP need some other methods.
Firstly the **CONNECTION** will be in FTP as default. Need to change to SFTP. 
Then instead of directly giving host name and password, it must be done in **Site manager**. Step by step procedure given below:

So the steps for troubleshooting:

1. Go to Filezilla's Settings
2. SFTP
3. Add Key File (Give the ppk converted key file or FZ will convert the pem ket)

Then take File in Filezilla 
Go to

1. File
2. Site Manager
3. New Site
4. Give any name (ec2-amazon)
5. In General, give host name 'Public DNS' (eg: ec2-34-423.ap-southeast...)
6. Change the Protocol to `SFTP`
7. Logon Type: `Normal`
8. User : `ec2-user` or `ubuntu` - depends
9. Clear Password
10. Connect!

Hope you will be connected. Happy Hosting...:)

Comment: While this might answer the question, in it's current format it's very hard to read. Consider rewording the answer to improve legibility.

Comment: @remus: Is it okay now?

Comment: Use some of SO's markdown formatting to clean up the bullet points maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following configuration in filezilla,
set Logon type = Interactive,Protocal = SFTP, and attach keyfile to filezilla SFTP setting from MenuBar -> Edit -> Settings ->SFTP -> Add Key File.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Setting this to interactive allowed me to enter the necessary password I had set on my ppk file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem-
I follow up @Amith Ajith answer but found my setting was as it, is.

1. I choose a file as privatekey.pem which i generated.
2. Change "Transfer setting" as active
   [image] 
   it worked for me.